Safe App Development - general questions
I am planning to use the Safe wallet for a DeFi dApp. I've been looking at Safe{Core} SDK documentation several times, but I still don't understand which kit I should use and install.
The final goal of this development is to launch the app inside https://app.safe.global/apps

Which Safe{Core} SDK kit do I need to use a Safe wallet and make transactions from it? Or is there a different tool I should be using? Please share any documentation links to help me start the development

Is it possible to use Vue.js with Safe Wallet integration?

Is there any wagmi-like kit or other tools I can use with it with Vue.js?


Appreciate any help with these questions. Thank you so much!

You are likely looking to create a Safe App and would need to use the Safe Apps SDK (and not the Safe{Core} SDK). Here's a link to the documentation for that: https://help.safe.global/en/articles/145503-how-to-create-a-safe-app-with-safe-apps-sdk-and-list-it
All the examples have been written in React. However, the Safe Apps SDK is written in JavaScript, so I believe it should also work with Vue.js apps.
Here's a link to the safe-apps-wagmi package (also linked in the docs link that I shared above): https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-apps-wagmi
I hope that helps!
